# How can I make this function be excluded from Org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I have this function

```
;; Move the point to the first non-whitespace character of the line.
;; If the point is already there, then move it to the beginning of the line.

(defun my/smarter-beginning-of-line ()
  (interactive)
  (if (= (point) (progn (back-to-indentation) (point)))
      (beginning-of-line)))

(keymap-global-set "C-a" 'my/smarter-beginning-of-line)
```

The function above works great when writing code:

```
1      var abc = 5; _
2      ^
3      |
4 ^    the first time I press C-a
5 |
6 the second time I press C-a
```

However in Org mode, I would like to use the default function which is `org-beginning-of-line`. If I use my custom function in Org mode then the point jumps to the beginning of a paragraph instead of the beginning of the line like `org-beginning-of-line` does.

How can I have my function only activate in non-org buffers? or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind that key to what it's normally bound to in Org mode:

```lisp
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-a") 'org-beginning-of-line)
```

Comment: Where do I need to define that? It doesn't seem to override the custom function's behavior.

Comment: Define it anywhere you like. It just binds that key in the Org-mode keymap. If that doesn't solve the problem then bisect your init file to find some other code that's binding that key to something else in `org-mode-map`. You can also use `describe-keymap` for `org-mode-map`, to see what that key's bound to.